# How do I pass variables from the controller to the view in laravel react?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm using laravel in my backend and react as my frontend. When I try to pass variables from my controller to the view with this:

```
public function index()      
{ 
  return view('welcome')->with('name', 'San Juan Vacation');
}
```

And want to retrieve it in my welcome blade file with this:

```
<p>{{ $name }}</p>
```

It doesn't work for some reason.
It says undefined variable $name. Any idea what might solve this issue?

Comment: Just replace this part of code ->with(['name'=> 'San Juan Vacation']);

Answer (score 1):

Pass variable `Controller` to `view`

```
public function index()      
{ 
   $name = 'San Juan Vacation';
   $color = 'red';
  // .....
  return view('welcome', compact('name', 'color'));
}
```

If you want to pass `with`, that time :

```
return view('welcome')->with(['name'=>$name,'color'=>$color]);
```

Write in `welcome.blade.php`

```
 <p>{{ $name }}</p>
```

I hope this work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

To send data from a controller to the view use this code: (you were close)

```
public function index()      
{ 
  $name = 'San Juan Vacation';
  $color = 'red';
  // .....
  return View::make('welcome', compact('name', 'color'));
}

<p>{{ $name }}</p>
```

Comment: It still says not defined. Do I need to define it into a constructor when loading the page?

Comment: Are you sure the route is applying to the right controller? you can try also php artisan view:clear

Comment: @ShehbanPatel Do you have the route set like Route::get('/something', 'YourController@index')->name('something.index')

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like my route was wrong which was causing these errors in the first place.

Comment: Cool, let me know if you still have some trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Modify you code as below

```
public function index()      
{   
    $name = "San Juan Vacation";
    return view('welcome')->with(['name'=>$name]);
}
```

Note: Avoid passing hard coded value to blade file, set variable for each.